# Unary negation operator overloading in D

Tags: operator-overloading, d

Code

```
struct test
{
   private real value;

   this(real value)
   {
      this.value = value;
   }

   bool opUnary(string op)() if (op == "!")
   {
      return !value;
   }
}

void main()
{
   test a = 123.12345;
   bool b = !a;
}
```

Compilation error

```
prog.d(19): Error: expression a of type test does not have a boolean value
```

http://ideone.com/Kec81

Also tested on dmd 2.053, 2.054

What's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot overload the `!` operator in D - see http://www.d-programming-language.org/operatoroverloading.html#Unary for a list of overloadable unary operators. Without knowing what you're doing, it's hard to suggest a work around, it might be worth looking at `alias this` though - http://www.d-programming-language.org/class.html#AliasThis.

Comment: Thanks. It seems you are right. This is an example from The D Programming Language. It seems I need to overload cast(bool) instead.

Comment: Note that all the logical operators are missing. IIRC that is intentional.